# javax.servlet cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

For some reason when I add my Tomcat server to eclipse and a project for servlets it isn't adding the appropriate jars and I'm getting the error "javax.servlet cannot be resolved to a type"

Here's my build path settings, as you can see there's no .jars under my Tomcat server:

[image]

Here are my tomcat server settings:

[image]

And here are the errors:

[image]

Comment: I think this has more to do with javax.servlet not being included. Are you using maven? Did you add it as a dependency?

Comment: @joe pls try what i have suggested.

Comment: Yeah im using maven, I just have M2eclipse installed

Answer (score 2):

Please try below settings, this should work.

In `Project Properties (Right Click on Project -> Properties), in Java Build Path`, add Library "Server Runtime". Adding this will add `servlet-api.jar` to project dependencies.

`select your project` → then click on project `menu bar on top` → `goto to properties` → click on `Targeted Runtimes` → now you must `select a check box next to the server` you are using to run current project → `click Apply` → then click OK button

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading a tar/zip from Apache directly, and using the location you unpack it into as the "installation directory."