# Adding tomcat server runtime doesn't add libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I was previously getting errors when trying to create a servlet in eclipse, I was getting the error "cannot resolve the type: javax.servlet" and noticed that none of the tomcat jars in the library were imported so I just imported the servlet-api.jar file in the tomcat lib folder which solved the issue. However this will become a headache if I have to do this for every jar I need and I've heard that it isn't recommended to import the single jars from tomcat. So why can't I import the jars from tomcat when I add the Tomcat server to my libraries? Here are some of my settings with the previous issue:

[javax.servlet cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096301/javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Comment: Eclipse will not import the jars from tomact though its added. You may need to manually import all libraries to your project!

Comment: Are you sure? I'm sure I read that by adding tomcat as a server runtime to your libraries all the libraries in the lib folder were automatically added.